# Using While loop to complete the following equation

Tags: c

I'm trying to write a program which prompts users for a number `x`, and finds the largest `n` that
satisfies the following equation:
1² + 2² + 3² + ... + `n`² < `x`.

First I need to know what my program is doing wrong, I've been trying to modify it for hours only to get infinite loops etc. I know this is an error in my logic; I just need to know what logic to use to complete the problem.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

int main(void)
{
    int number;

    printf("Please enter a number\n");
    scanf("%d", &number);

    double c = 1; // stores number
    double n = 0;

    while (n < number)
    {
        n = c + pow(c, 2);
        c++;    
    }    
    printf("The largest n is %lf\n", c);
    printf("%lf", n);

    return 0;    
}
```

Comment: Are you sure the `while` loop is like your equation?

Comment: Use a debugger.  Set a breakpoint at the top of your program, and step through it line-by-line.  Watch the value of each variable at each step.

Comment: You need to be more specific with your error description: exactly what is *this code in your question* doing? How is that different from what you expected? Saying that you tried a bunch of different things and they didn't work, doesn't tell us anything about the code that you've actually presented here.

Comment: or get out a pen and paper, pick some value for x and then go through your code by hand. If you let x = 6, then you know that n should return as 2 and that should happen pretty fast. You should be able to see your errors immediately

Comment: Please name stuff in such a way that makes sense.  'number' is just horrible.  'seriesLimit' might be better.  'currentTotal' may be good for the accumulator, 'termIndex' for, well, the index of the term.  Single-letter var names confuse us, and yourself.

Comment: Did you mean to use floating-point types?  Comparing two FP values that you think should be equal may well not work as you expect.

Comment: 'I've been trying to modify it for hours only to get infinte loops etc.' - no, no, no! See @abelenky comment above about debugging.

Comment: @miss.serena presents a viable option.  Your program is so short you should be able to "run it by hand".  (But I'd really prefer that you use a debugger.  It is an ***essential*** professional skill.  I will never hire someone who cannot use a debugger)

Answer (score 1):

Here you are.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main( void )
{
    while ( 1 )
    {        
        printf( "Enter a positive number (0-exit): " );
        unsigned int number;

        if ( !( scanf( "%u", &number ) == 1 ) || number == 0 ) break;

        unsigned int n = 0;
        unsigned long long sum = 0;

        while ( ( sum + ( unsigned long long )( n + 1 ) * ( n + 1 ) ) < number ) 
        {
            ++n;
            sum += ( unsigned long long )n * n;
        }            

        printf( "The largest n is %u and the corresponding sum is %llu\n", n, sum );
    }       
}
```

If to enter for example `65` and then `0` then the output might look like

```
Enter a positive number (0-exit): 65
The largest n is 5 and the corresponding sum is 55
Enter a positive number (0-exit): 0
```

If you want you can change the type of the variable `number` from `unsigned int` to `double`. All you else need to do in this case is to change the format specifier for `scanf`.

As for your program then the loop itself

```
while (n < number)
{
    n = c + pow(c, 2);
    c++;    
}
```

is wrong because within the loop `n` can become greater than the number and `c` will be increased.

Also instead of

```
n = c + pow(c, 2);
```

there must be

```
n += c * c;
```

Comment: @chux I have added the casting.:)

Comment: @chux Actually there is no need to use the casting because n * n can not be greater than UINT_MAX.

Answer (score 1):

You should use integers rather than double and remember to decrement c in the end (since the last c is the first one which is actually GREATER than your input).

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

int main(void)
{
    int number;

    printf("Please enter a number\n");
    scanf("%i", &number);

    int c = 1; // stores number
    int n = 0;

    while (n < number) {
        n += c*c;
        c++;    
    }    
    printf("The largest n is %i\n", --c);

    return 0;    
}
```

Comment: So `n` is just `c + c*c`?  Maybe you wanted `n += c*c;`

Comment: sorry I pasted your original code instead of mine :). Check again, I've replaced it..

Comment: `c*c` is better than `pow(c, 2)` as the latter is a double; also, you probably want an `unsigned long` for `n` (or better, `while (n < number - c*c) { n+= c*c; ++c; }`) to avoid overflow.

Answer (score 0):

I think your program is not computing the right `c` value, if you simply add 1 to `c` in each iteration then at the end `c` will be equal to the number of iterations, try this

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int
main(void)
{
    double x = 0;
    double y = 0;
    double z = 0;
    if (scanf("%lf", &x) != 1)
        return -1;
    for (double n = 0 ; y < x ; ++n)
    {
        z = y; // Store the value before `y' >= `x'
        y = y + pow(n, 2); // Update `y'
    }
    fprintf(stdout, "%f\n", z);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
n = c + pow(c, 2);
```

Doesn't do what you think would do. In order to sum to the value correctly because you never saved your previous sum correctly.

```
int main(void) {    
    int number;

    printf("Please enter a number\n");
    scanf("%d", &number);

    double c = 1; //stores number
    double n = 0;
    double prev = 0;

    while (n<number)
    {
        prev = n;
        n += pow(c, 2);
        c++;

    }

    printf("The largest n is %lf\n", prev);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Instead of just posting a block of code, you should add some comments or explanation of why it fixes the issue.

Comment: Sure, I will add something